# read files with loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am reading all files from a directory. But then I want to loop over it and load the files with the number of iterator of the loop, like this

```
A = dir('*.txt');
for i=1:size(A)
   text = function('Text'+i+'.txt');
end
```

So my problem is, I can't find the right syntax to get the text file at the i-position.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't simply `add` strings like `'Text'` and numbers `i`.
You'll have to convert `i` to a string first and then concatenate the three:

```
text = function(['Text', num2str(i), '.txt']);
```

Alternatively, my preferred solution would be to use `sprintf`:

```
text = function(sprintf('Text%i.txt', i));
```

`sprintf` will replace the `%i` part in the string by the integer-representation of `i`.

**EDIT:**

Re-reading your question, you might be better off using the information from `dir` instead of *building* your own filenames:

```
text = function(A(i).name);
```

The structure `A` will contain information on every file - including its name.
This would make your code somewhat more stable.

Comment: Thank you! My problem is, there are more *.txt files in the directory than I want use. Is it possible to say something like "add every file to A which starts with the letter 't' and has the extension '.txt'?

Comment: Well, you can obviously do `A = dir('t*.txt')`.